# Import a dependency to a service worker

Tags: webpack, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, workbox

Until now I have been using `importScripts` to import external dependencies into my service worker. But now I see in the documentation of two of my dependencies that to use their latest version I should be using the `import` statement:

1. [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#web-version-9)
2. [Google Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started#using_workbox)

Everywhere else I look (here on SO or just by Googling) it says to use `importScripts` in service worker. So am I missing something?

I am using Webpack as bundler.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, in some browsers, [to use runtime ES module imports](https://web.dev/es-modules-in-sw/) to pull additional code into the `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`. The lack of universal browser support means that you might have trouble relying on that exclusively.

Because of this, it's still very common to do one of two things:

- Use ES module imports as a build-time signal to a bundler, like Rollup/webpack/esbuild, to include code in a final service worker bundle that ends up being run in the browser. This is what the documentation for, e.g., Workbox steers folks towards, and [includes examples of](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/using-workbox-without-precaching/#when-using-a-bundler). This approach means that the bundler can eliminate code that you don't end up referencing from the Workbox packages you import.
- Use `importScripts()`, as before. This is still [supported in Workbox](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/modules/workbox-sw/), even though it's not the preferred approach.

Comment: The key point here is to signal to the bundler that you are indeed using modules. For webpack it means adding `"type": "module"` to the package.json. Please add this to your answer and I will accept it.